# contact form 7 form not working in admin panel

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using cf7 form in wordpress admin panel:
[image]

On front end its working fine but I need in admin panel. I have tried below code in functions.php but it did not work:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_css', '__return_false' );

function cf7_script_and_style() {
   // add here the logic to return if this isn't the contact page
   if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts' ) ) wpcf7_enqueue_scripts();
   if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_styles' ) ) wpcf7_enqueue_styles();
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cf7_script_and_style' ); //or wp_footer or wp_body_open etc
```

When I submit it, it just reload the page, No email is received. Ajax is also disabled so I believe scripts are not loaded in admin panel.
What is your suggestions on it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The action `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook is only on the frontend: try changing this to `admin_enqueue_scripts` for the admin (untested):

```php
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cf7_script_and_style' );
```

**Edit:**

After looking at [the definition for `wpcf7_enqueue_scripts()`](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/controller.php), it turns out that CF7 doesn't anticipate being loaded in the admin: who would've guessed. You'll need to copy a lot of that file and adjust it to work in the admin (using `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`).

Comment: I tried admin_enqueue_scripts but still same issue. nothing changed :(

Comment: Took a look at the source code and updated my answer.

Comment: okay I will have to make custom form then